# How not to select the last element

Tags: jquery, twitter

So I am building a twitter like web app in jquery/html/php. When I user scrolls down to the end of the page more twits load (just like on twitter). The problem I have that inside each twit div there is a div (class .details) that is showing reply to the original twit, and that reply twit also has the same class as the original twit.

Better explained with code:

```
<div id="twit_id_{$twits[i].TID}" class="twit">    
    twit content
    <div>
        <div class="details">
            <div id="twit_id_{$twits[i].TID}" class="twit">
                twit content
            <div>
        </div>
```

And with this jquery I get the latest twit id and send it to php, but I don`t want the id from the details. I want the last id from the page, but not the id inside details.

```
var end_id = $(".twit:last").attr("id");
```

I tried something like this, did not work.

```
var end_id = $(".twit:last").not('.details').attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
var end_id = $(".twit:not(.details .twit):last").attr("id");
```

[edit] Looked a bit closer and realised that this is what you want.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wUv8k/

Comment: Thanks, this worked. And thanks to the mod that made my code nicer, third time posting a question on stack and forgot about the code tags.